# Overlap svg icons on another Image in Ionic 4. Need it to be responsive

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to achieve a icons image attached which should be responsive in all the screens and should not shrink or move in any of the screens.  There are total 4 images 1 is the background image and the other three are the svg icons.

[image: This is what i am trying to achieve.]

---

```
 <ion-row>
 <ion-col text-center class="icons middle" size="12">
<ion-img class="icons1" style="margin-left: auto ; margin-right: auto; " 
 class="whitecircle" src="../../../assets/login/white_circle.svg"></ion-img>
    <ion-row text-center class="icon-row">
      <ion-col class="icons2">
        <ion-img src="../../../assets/login/facebook_logo.svg"></ion-img>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col class=" icons3">
        <ion-img src="../../../assets/login/twitter_logo.svg"></ion-img>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col class=" icons4">
        <ion-img src="../../../assets/login/google_logo.svg"></ion-img>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

---

```
.icon-row{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.icons{
    display: grid;
    width: 42px;
}
.icons1{
    grid-row: row 1;
}

.icons2{
    grid-row: row 1/ span 3;
}

.icons3{
    grid-row: row 1/ span 3;
}

.icons4{
    grid-row: row 1/ span 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have said is a contradiction.

- "Responsive" means that it adjusts.
- "It should not shrink or move" means that it is not responsive.

The `ion-row` and `ion-col` feature is for building a responsive structure.

If you don't want that then just put everything in a single `div`.

You can apply the css `white-space: nowrap;` to the div so that it won't break up the contents no matter the size of the display.